# My webpage is not displaying the text from a different html page. (javascript/jquery/ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

In this project, I am creating a contact.js file for the contact.html file that will pull the data from the listings.html file and append its entire contents to the aboutUs div in the contact.html page. I wrote a function to make the contents from the listings.html file appear in the contact.html file, but when I opened up my webpage, the contents were still not displayed. What am I doing wrong here.

I am using a contact.html file, a contact,js file, and a listings.html file (and a jquery file).

My contact.html file is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Real Estate Sold</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="listing.css" />

         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="contact.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

<nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
<div>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Regional Info</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">Current Listings</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sold</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
</ul></div>
</nav>


        <div id="aboutUs"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My contact.html file is this:

```
 $("document").ready(function() {
        getData();
      });

      function getData() {
        $("#aboutUs").load("listings.html");
      }
```

My listings.html file is this:

```
<h2>About Us</h2>
<p>Wright Realty is a family owned real estate brokerage specializing in custom homes since 1852.  
    We appreciate that our customers demand quality that endures for generations, so we only
    list with homeowners who have maticulously maintained their unique and timeless homes.</p>
    <h3>Our Realtors:</h3>
    <ul></ul>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: Try `$(document)` instead of `$("document")`.

Comment: None at all. It's blank.

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried that and it still won't work.

Comment: @nnnnnn quoted `document` is fine jQuery will accept that!

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Can you explain to me why the contents from the listings.html are not appearing on the webpage?

Comment: Make sure that `listings.html` is in root directory, as well as `jquery-1.11.1.js` as well as `contact.js`. Check console for errors.

Comment: @mayrop They are all in the root directory and there are no errors in the console. What now?

Comment: Try this and let me know if you see the alert : `$( "#aboutUs" ).load("listings.html", function() { alert( "Load success!" ); });`

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I tried your code and when I loaded the webpage, these messages displayed in my console window :

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8020/WrightRealty/jquery-1.11.1.js"
jquery-1.11.1.js
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$("document").ready(function() {

 
contact.js (line 2, col 2)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8020/images/corkboard_tile.jpg"

Comment: So it did not print "Load success!".

Comment: Try to replace `jquery-1.11.1.js` by `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js` and see the result !

Comment: I tried that, but the console window is still displaying ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$("document").ready(function() {

Comment: Are you sure ? `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>` ??

Comment: Sadly, I am. I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: It works!!! I just had to add the <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script> right before my contact.js! Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Congrats! anyway here is a working demo https://plnkr.co/edit/x5E3RU2GikYli2qQGoQX?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, that is what mine looks like as well!! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Switch to HTML5, you are using HTML5 tags in an XHTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are loading the file using *file://* which is not allowed. You have to use *http://* instead.

You can use *http-server* to quickly start a server:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

To use it:

```
cd *your folder*
http-server
```